# API call to list_subscribers timing out

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk

I am trying to access a list of subscribers that exists inside ET via your API calls, but am receiving a **time out error** (even when just querying a single list).

This seems to be some sort of performance issue on your side as the list is small (<20 people) but I have not been able to successfully retrieve it.

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
JMoneyMacBook:sendgrid-stats jsinclair$ python et-list-subscriber.py 
>>> Retrieve all Subscribers on List 1391770
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "et-list-subscriber.py", line 31, in 
main()
File "et-list-subscriber.py", line 27, in main
getSubscribersOnList(curr_list)
File "et-list-subscriber.py", line 13, in getSubscribersOnList
getResponse = getListSubs.get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/FuelSDK/rest.py", line 288, in get
obj = ET_Get(self.auth_stub, self.obj_type, props, search_filter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/FuelSDK/rest.py", line 192, in __init__
response = auth_stub.soap_client.service.Retrieve(ws_retrieveRequest) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 538, in __call__
return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
result = self.send(soapenv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 637, in send
reply = transport.send(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
return HttpTransport.send(self, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 77, in send
fp = self.u2open(u2request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in u2open
return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
context=self._context)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1200, in do_open
r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 734, in recv
return self.read(bu`enter code here`flen)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 621, in read
v = self._sslobj.read(len or 1024)
ssl.SSLError: ('The read operation timed out',)
```

Comment: Any help here? This is still a problem and I don't seem to have any way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue.  Try setting a larger timeout.  This option isn't anywhere in the FuelSDK documentation.  I had to dig into FuelSDK and SUDS source.  SUDS default timeout is 90 seconds.

https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/src/94664ddd46a61d06862fa8fb6ba7b9e054214f57/suds/transport/options.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

```
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client()
myClient.soap_client.set_options(timeout=300)
```

Hope this helps!